# Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route [product.details] not defined

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am getting an routing error in my laravel project

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route
> [product.details] not defined. (View:
> C:\wamp\www\EAnimal\resources\views\livewire\shop-component.blade.php)

App/Http/Livewire/ShopComponent.php

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ShopComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public function render()
    {   

        $products= Product::paginate(12);
        return view('livewire.shop-component',['products'=>$products])->layout('layout.base');
    }
}
```

Here is my Route
Web.php

```
 <?php
    use App\Http\Livewire\HomeComponent;
    use App\Http\Livewire\ShopComponent;
    use App\Http\Livewire\CartComponent;
    use App\Http\Livewire\CheckoutComponent;
    use App\Http\Livewire\DetailsComponent;
    
    use App\http\Livewire\Admin\AdminDashboardComponent;
    use App\http\Livewire\User\UserDashboardComponent;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */
    
    /*Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });*/
    
    
    Route::get('/',HomeComponent::class);
    Route::get('/shop',ShopComponent::class);
    Route::get('/cart',CartComponent::class);
    Route::get('/checkout',CheckoutComponent::class);
    Route::get('/product/{slug}',DetailsComponent::class)->name('product.details');
    
    // Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    //     return view('dashboard');
    // })->name('dashboard');
    
    
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified'])->group(function(){
            Route::get('/user/dashboard',UserDashboardComponent::class)->name('user.dashboard');
    });
    
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified','authadmin'])->group(function(){
            Route::get('/admin/dashboard',AdminDashboardComponent::class)->name('admin.dashboard');
    });
```

ShopComponent.blade.php

```
<main id="main" class="main-site left-sidebar">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="wrap-breadcrumb">
                <ul>
                    <li class="item-link"><a href="#" class="link">home</a></li>
                    <li class="item-link"><span>Digital & Electronics</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 main-content-area">

                    <div class="banner-shop">
                        <a href="#" class="banner-link">
                            <figure><img src="assets/images/shop-banner.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-shop-control">

                        <h1 class="shop-title">Digital & Electronics</h1>

                        <div class="wrap-right">

                            <div class="sort-item orderby ">
                                <select name="orderby" class="use-chosen" >
                                    <option value="menu_order" selected="selected">Default sorting</option>
                                    <option value="popularity">Sort by popularity</option>
                                    <option value="rating">Sort by average rating</option>
                                    <option value="date">Sort by newness</option>
                                    <option value="price">Sort by price: low to high</option>
                                    <option value="price-desc">Sort by price: high to low</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="sort-item product-per-page">
                                <select name="post-per-page" class="use-chosen" >
                                    <option value="12" selected="selected">12 per page</option>
                                    <option value="16">16 per page</option>
                                    <option value="18">18 per page</option>
                                    <option value="21">21 per page</option>
                                    <option value="24">24 per page</option>
                                    <option value="30">30 per page</option>
                                    <option value="32">32 per page</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="change-display-mode">
                                <a href="#" class="grid-mode display-mode active"><i class="fa fa-th"></i>Grid</a>
                                <a href="list.html" class="list-mode display-mode"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>List</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div><!--end wrap shop control-->

                    <div class="row">

                        <ul class="product-list grid-products equal-container">
                            @foreach($products as $product)
                            <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                                <div class="product product-style-3 equal-elem ">
                                    <div class="product-thumnail">
                                        <a href="{{route('product.details',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}" title="{{$product->name}}">
                                            <figure><img src="assets/images/products/digital_20.jpg" alt="{{$product->name}}"></figure>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-info">
                                        <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>{{$product->name}}</span></a>
                                        <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">{{$product->regular_price}}</span></div>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add To Cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            @endforeach

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-pagination-info">
                        <ul class="page-numbers">
                            <li><span class="page-number-item current" >1</span></li>
                            <li><a class="page-number-item" href="#" >2</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-number-item" href="#" >3</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-number-item next-link" href="#" >Next</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="result-count">Showing 1-8 of 12 result</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end main products area-->

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 sitebar">
                    <div class="widget mercado-widget categories-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">All Categories</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="list-category">
                                <li class="category-item has-child-cate">
                                    <a href="#" class="cate-link">Fashion & Accessories</a>
                                    <span class="toggle-control">+</span>
                                    <ul class="sub-cate">
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Batteries (22)</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Headsets (16)</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Screen (28)</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="category-item has-child-cate">
                                    <a href="#" class="cate-link">Furnitures & Home Decors</a>
                                    <span class="toggle-control">+</span>
                                    <ul class="sub-cate">
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Batteries (22)</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Headsets (16)</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Screen (28)</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="category-item has-child-cate">
                                    <a href="#" class="cate-link">Digital & Electronics</a>
                                    <span class="toggle-control">+</span>
                                    <ul class="sub-cate">
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Batteries (22)</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Headsets (16)</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-item"><a href="#" class="cate-link">Screen (28)</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="category-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="cate-link">Tools & Equipments</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="category-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="cate-link">Kid’s Toys</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="category-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="cate-link">Organics & Spa</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Categories widget-->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget filter-widget brand-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Brand</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="list-style vertical-list list-limited" data-show="6">
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link active" href="#">Fashion Clothings</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Laptop Batteries</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Printer & Ink</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">CPUs & Prosecsors</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Sound & Speaker</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Shop Smartphone & Tablets</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item default-hiden"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Printer & Ink</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item default-hiden"><a class="filter-link " href="#">CPUs & Prosecsors</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item default-hiden"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Sound & Speaker</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item default-hiden"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Shop Smartphone & Tablets</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a data-label='Show less<i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>' class="btn-control control-show-more" href="#">Show more<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- brand widget-->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget filter-widget price-filter">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Price</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <div id="slider-range"></div>
                            <p>
                                <label for="amount">Price:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="amount" readonly>
                                <button class="filter-submit">Filter</button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Price-->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget filter-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Color</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="list-style vertical-list has-count-index">
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Red <span>(217)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Yellow <span>(179)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Black <span>(79)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Blue <span>(283)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Grey <span>(116)</span></a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">Pink <span>(29)</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Color -->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget filter-widget">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Size</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="list-style inline-round ">
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link active" href="#">s</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">M</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">l</a></li>
                                <li class="list-item"><a class="filter-link " href="#">xl</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="widget-banner">
                                <figure><img src="assets/images/size-banner-widget.jpg" width="270" height="331" alt=""></figure>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- Size -->

                    <div class="widget mercado-widget widget-product">
                        <h2 class="widget-title">Popular Products</h2>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <ul class="products">
                                <li class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product product-widget-style">
                                        <div class="thumbnnail">
                                            <a href="detail.html" title="Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker [White]">
                                                <figure><img src="assets/images/products/digital_01.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker...</span></a>
                                            <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">$168.00</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product product-widget-style">
                                        <div class="thumbnnail">
                                            <a href="detail.html" title="Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker [White]">
                                                <figure><img src="assets/images/products/digital_17.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker...</span></a>
                                            <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">$168.00</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product product-widget-style">
                                        <div class="thumbnnail">
                                            <a href="detail.html" title="Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker [White]">
                                                <figure><img src="assets/images/products/digital_18.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker...</span></a>
                                            <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">$168.00</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product product-widget-style">
                                        <div class="thumbnnail">
                                            <a href="detail.html" title="Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker [White]">
                                                <figure><img src="assets/images/products/digital_20.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-info">
                                            <a href="#" class="product-name"><span>Radiant-360 R6 Wireless Omnidirectional Speaker...</span></a>
                                            <div class="wrap-price"><span class="product-price">$168.00</span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- brand widget-->

                </div><!--end sitebar-->

            </div><!--end row-->

        </div><!--end container-->

    </main>
```

Comment: can you list your routes in console? is this product.details shown?

Comment: Yes, product.details is showing on console when i checked php artisan route:list

Comment: |        | GET|HEAD | product/{slug}                   | product.details                 | App\Http\Livewire\DetailsComponent

Answer (score 0):

Try writing link this way

```
<a href="{{route('product.details',$product->slug)}}" title="{{$product->name}}">
```

Adding with key name in route will add a query string param and laravel route will not match it.

Comment: $product->slug have value on database